I am trying to animate an object in ursina but it doesn't work for me. How to fix?
    door1.animate_y = (18, duration=5)

I heard from another post to use 1 equal sign for duration.
I used 1 equal sign for duration and I though it would work, but it said invalid syntax.
When I use 2 equal signs, it can't identify duration.
Can somebody help me?
-Developer

Please read [ask] and [mre], then come back and [edit] your question.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You're trying to set door1.animate_y to a value. I think what you meant to do was to call the animate_y function. You'd do that like this:
door1.animate_y(18, duration=5)

